# magento 2 list-inconsistencies gets killed

Tags: magento2, php, cli

I'm using the the command:

```
bin/magento inventory:reservation:list-inconsistencies -r | bin/magento inventory:reservation:create-compensations
```

However the first part gets killed, and so this is piped into the second part.
how do i debug this? Where does magento log what killed this script?